# dynamically register transaction listener with spring?

Tags: spring, transactions, jta

I have a springframework application in which I would like to add a transaction listener to a transaction which is currently in progress.  The motivation is to trigger a post commit action which notifies downstream systems.  I am using @Transactional to wrap a transaction around some service method -- which is where I want to create/register the post transaction listener.  I want to do something "like" the following.

```
public class MyService {
 @Transaction
 public void doIt() {
  modifyObjects();

  // something like this
  getTransactionManager().registerPostCommitAction(new 
   TransactionSynchronizationAdapter() {
     public void afterCommit() { 
      notifyDownstream(); 
     }
  });
 }
}
```

Spring has a TransactionSynchronization interface and adapter class which seems exactly what I want; however it is not immediately clear how to register one dynamically with either the current transaction, or the transaction manager.  I would rather not subclass JtaTransactionManager if I can avoid it.

**Q:** Has anyone done this before.

**Q:** what is the simplest way to register my adapter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use an [aspect to match](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/aop.html#aop-advice-after-returning) transactional methods aspect in your service to accomplish this:

```
@Aspect
public class AfterReturningExample {

  @AfterReturning("execution(* com.mypackage.MyService.*(..))")
  public void afterReturning() {
    // ...
  }

}
```

Comment: A good suggestion, however, won't this execute in any transaction? I only want sucesful completion.  Also, can I use those AOP annotations with default spring (I'm not using code weaving) just JDK proxies.

Comment: Return advice does not run when methods throw exception, so this relies on @Transactional committing when method returns result and rolling back when throwing exception, which is generally what happens.  The aspects are called through springs dynamic proxies so it doesn't do any code weaving (unless you don't provide interfaces for spring to proxy, where spring will fall back to weaving code in at runtime with cglib).

Comment: +1 for interesting, but i'm still not convinced without testing.  There are at least 2 @AfterReturning involved: @Transactional and then my custom Aspect.  If @Transactional runs, then mine runs all is well; however in the other order I will execute before -- independently of the transaction commit status.

Answer (score 30):

Actually it was not as hard as I thought; spring has a static helper class that puts the 'right' stuff into the thread context.

```
TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(
    new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void afterCommit() {
            s_logger.info("TRANSACTION COMPLETE!!!");
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: +1 for a nice and straightforward answer.  I didn't know that TransactionSynchronizationManager existed.

Comment: Actually this solution is not as good as I had though.  The contract for TransactionSynchronizationManager is more extensive, and trying to send a JMS message from within the afterCommit() fails (with no exception) since the above code does follow the contract.

Comment: Most Spring messaging solutions (JMS,AMQP) allow you to plugin in your transaction manager into them so that transactions between the two systems (db, message broker) are synchronized. I didn't want to do this because RabbitMQ TX are very slow. Consequently you might want to look at my solution.

Comment: TransactionSynchronizationAdapter is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more complete solution I did for a similar problem that with wanting my messages sent after transactions are committed (I could have used RabbitMQ TX but they are rather slow).

```
public class MessageBusUtils {
    public static Optional<MessageBusResourceHolder> getTransactionalResourceHolder(TxMessageBus messageBus) {

        if ( ! TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()) {
            return Optional.absent();
        }

        MessageBusResourceHolder o = (MessageBusResourceHolder) TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource(messageBus);
        if (o != null) return Optional.of(o);

        o = new MessageBusResourceHolder();
        TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(messageBus, o);
        o.setSynchronizedWithTransaction(true);
        if (TransactionSynchronizationManager.isSynchronizationActive()) {
            TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new MessageBusResourceSynchronization(o, messageBus));
        }
        return Optional.of(o);

    }

    private static class MessageBusResourceSynchronization extends ResourceHolderSynchronization<MessageBusResourceHolder, TxMessageBus> {
        private final TxMessageBus messageBus;
        private final MessageBusResourceHolder holder;

        public MessageBusResourceSynchronization(MessageBusResourceHolder resourceHolder, TxMessageBus resourceKey) {
            super(resourceHolder, resourceKey);
            this.messageBus = resourceKey;
            this.holder = resourceHolder;
        }


        @Override
        protected void cleanupResource(MessageBusResourceHolder resourceHolder, TxMessageBus resourceKey,
                boolean committed) {
            resourceHolder.getPendingMessages().clear();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterCompletion(int status) {
            if (status == TransactionSynchronization.STATUS_COMMITTED) {
                for (Object o : holder.getPendingMessages()) {
                    messageBus.post(o, false);
                }
            }
            else {
                holder.getPendingMessages().clear();
            }
            super.afterCompletion(status);
        }


    }
}

public class MessageBusResourceHolder extends ResourceHolderSupport {

    private List<Object> pendingMessages = Lists.newArrayList();

    public void addMessage(Object message) {
        pendingMessages.add(message);
    }


    protected List<Object> getPendingMessages() {
        return pendingMessages;
    }

}
```

Now in your class where you actually send the message you will do

```
@Override
public void postAfterCommit(Object o) {
    Optional<MessageBusResourceHolder> holder = MessageBusTxUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(this);
    if (holder.isPresent()) {
        holder.get().addMessage(o);
    }
    else {
        post(o, false);
    }
}
```

Sorry for the long winded coding samples but hopefully that will show someone how to do something after a commit.

Comment: I'm using your code to update 3 solr index after the transaction committed. I'm also using Spring event to detect modification of Business Objects, stores event in the ResourceHolder, and update index who need to be update asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Does it make sense to override the transaction manager on the commit and rollback methods, calling `super.commit()` right at the beginning.