# Transaction based cache eviction

Tags: java, caching, guava, ehcache

I'm wondering if it's possible to have "transaction based" cache eviction. Currently what I was using was guava time based eviction (for instance 5 sec after last read) - now I've got requirement, that I want to clear cache when transaction is being commited.

I don't see such option in guava, but maybe EhCache can help here?

Any ideas how to approach this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you need to manually invalidate some entities, right? I mean after commit, evict them:

[Manually evict some key in cache](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#invalidate(java.lang.Object))

Comment: Ok, so how I can determine some "PostTransaction"? Becasue I'm having transactional DAO class, and I want to perform some custom action after transaction commits (the one related to operations on this DAO)

Comment: @Karol how about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357535/dynamically-register-transaction-listener-with-spring